# How to delete a part of a string between two patterns including one of them

Tags: bash, vim

I have a CSV document like this:

```
RL|S1|C19.concoct_part_0        concoct.26
RL|S1|C26.concoct_part_4        concoct.7
RL|S1|C26.concoct_part_5        concoct.7
```

I want it to be like this:

```
RL|S1|C19        concoct.26
RL|S1|C26        concoct.7
RL|S1|C26        concoct.7
```

How do I do it in Vim?

Comment: Have you tried `:%s/\.[^,]*//`?

Comment: hey sorry, I changed the task a bit

Comment: It's ok, just change comma to `\t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @oguz ismail the solution is the following

```
:%s/\.[^\t]*//
```

Answer (score 2):

Using command line mode you can run:

```
:%norm f.dt<space><enter>
```

Note: you must to type space and enter instead of writing it.